# dynamically add new fields to a osv model depending on the number of records of another osv model in openerp

Tags: odoo

How to dynamically add new fields to a osv model depending on the number of records of another osv model in openerp? For example
 I have a model which is for planning purchases. I need to show total order qty that came in each shop.so i need to add new field each time a new record in sale.shop is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `__init__` function of your class to dynamically add the sales shop to `_columns`.

```
class planning(osv.osv):
    def __init__(self, pool, cr):
        shop_ids = pool.get('sale.shop').search(cr,SUPERUSER_ID,[])
        for shop in pool.get('sale.shop').browse(cr, SUPERUSER_ID,shop_ids):
            self._columns['shop_qty_%s'%shop.id] = fields.float(
                                                                '%s Order Qty'%shop.name)
        return super(planning,self).__init__(pool, cr)
```